# Superset How to add a filter in dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

Superset comes with an example named "World's Bank Data". In its dashboard, there is a filter named "Region Filter". How can I implement this? Is there a tutorial on this? Any pointer or a quick explanation will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The old approach was to create a "filter box" slice.  It [was announced in 2022 (with version 1.5) that this approach is being deprecated](https://preset.io/blog/apache-superset-1-5-release-notes/) in favor of dashboard native filters.

As of version >=1.5.0 you add a dashboard native filter by clicking `+ADD/EDIT FILTERS` in the top left of the dashboard:

[image]

This filter panel can be collapsed, so you may need to click the expand arrow if it is hidden.

In Superset versions >= 2.1.0, the filter panel can be moved to the top of the dashboard in a horizontal layout if the feature flag `HORIZONTAL_FILTER_BAR` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use superset jinja templating, example:
`({{ "'" + "','".join(filter_values('platform')) + "'" }})`

Answer (score 0):

create a new chart and select the "filter box" and then add this to your dashboard